# Multiple chain draws for simple Multivariate Bernouilli inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, bayesian, tensorflow-probability

I want to perform a simple inference of a Multivariate Bernouilli (dimension D) with multiple chains. The code below works and correctly infers the parameters value for an unique chain.
I suspect that I incorrectly defined my model. I didn't find any simple example of simple bernouilli inference.

The error returned is: 
`ValueError: Dimension must be 3 but is 2 for 'mcmc_sample_chain/simple_step_size_adaptation___init__/_bootstrap_results/mh_bootstrap_results/hmc_kernel_bootstrap_results/maybe_call_fn_and_grads/value_and_gradients/mcmc_sample_chain_simple_step_size_adaptation___init____bootstrap_results_mh_bootstrap_results_hmc_kernel_bootstrap_results_maybe_call_fn_and_grads_value_and_gradients_Samplemcmc_sample_chain_simple_step_size_adaptation___init____bootstrap_results_mh_bootstrap_results_hmc_kernel_bootstrap_results_maybe_call_fn_and_grads_value_and_gradients_Independentmcmc_sample_chain_simple_step_size_adaptation___init____bootstrap_results_mh_bootstrap_results_hmc_kernel_bootstrap_results_maybe_call_fn_and_grads_value_and_gradients_Bernoulli/log_prob/transpose' (op: 'Transpose') with input shapes: [1,5000,2], [2].`

Here a simple example with D=2 and N = 5000 (number of samples in the training set).

```py
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import functools
tfd = tfp.distributions

# ---------- DATA Generator ------------#

def generate_bernouilli(N,p):
    return np.array([np.random.binomial(size=N, n=1, p = probability) for probability in p ]).T

D = 2
N = 5000
p = np.sort(np.random.random(D))

observations = generate_bernouilli(N,p)

# ---------- Model ------------#

def make_likelihood(theta):
    one_y = tfd.Independent(
        distribution = tfd.Bernoulli(probs=theta),
        reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)
    y = tfd.Sample(one_y,
          sample_shape=(N,))
    return y

def joint_log_prob(observations, theta):
    return (tf.reduce_sum(make_likelihood(theta).log_prob(observations)))

posterior_log_prob = functools.partial(joint_log_prob, observations)


# ---------- MCMC sampling  ------------#

num_results = int(10e3)
num_burnin_steps = int(1e3)
n_chains = 5

adaptive_hmc = tfp.mcmc.SimpleStepSizeAdaptation(
    tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
        target_log_prob_fn=posterior_log_prob,
        num_leapfrog_steps=3,
        step_size=1.),
    target_accept_prob=tf.constant(.8),
    num_adaptation_steps=int(num_burnin_steps * 0.8))


@tf.function
def run_chain():
# Run the chain (with burn-in).
    samples, is_accepted = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
    num_results=num_results,
    num_burnin_steps=num_burnin_steps,
    current_state=tf.ones([n_chains,2])/10,
    kernel=adaptive_hmc,
    trace_fn=lambda _, pkr: pkr.inner_results.is_accepted)

    is_accepted = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_accepted, dtype=tf.float32))
    return samples, is_accepted


# ---------- Run  ------------#
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
    samples, is_accepted = run_chain()
```

The code works perfectly if we replace current_state by `current_state=tf.ones([2])/10` (and thus removing the independent chain sampling.

I have few questions and I will be very grateful for any help:
+ Is my model correctly implemented ?
+ Is there a way to debug this type of error in tf ? The python debugger is not of much help.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am clearly not an expert in tensorflow probability, so this answer will most probably not be best practices, I just made it work with the limited knowledge I have on the library while trying to learn more of tensorflow probability myself.

Secondly, I am only aiming to answer the part of the question regarding the model and its implementation, to an answer about debugging tensorflow, either google a little about it to see if there are some tutorials about it, of ask another question as I feel it is a whole different question.

Regarding the model, it looks properly implemented, and I was able to make it work without much change, however, I would recommend explicitly using a prior on `theta` for two reasons. The first one is that even if you don't set it, a prior is being used (in general uniform which is a constant, in this case definitely a uniform prior, and an unbounded uniform prior) and you may not know which one it is or assume you are using a different model than the implemented one. The second one is that you may run into unexpected problems when using a prior not fit for the problem at hand. For example, here `theta` is a vector of dimension `D` which must be between `0` and `1`, however, in your implementation `theta` can take values outside this range; luckily, if the parameter of a `tfd.Bernoulli` is outside `(0,1)` tensorflow simply returns `nan`, but this may not always be the case, it could throw an error (which would be triggered at the *random* iteration where theta lies outside `(0,1)`) or you could simply get incomprehensible results where the probability of heads is `1.3`.

Thus, I added a prior and modified the following points of the code:

- I added an extra dimension to `observations` so that it could be properly broadcast
- I used the `distribution.log_prob()` instead of `log_prob` of `tfd.Sample`. I have tried to use `log_prob` directly, but I have trouble understanding how `tfd.Sample` works and how does it affect `log_prog` of the original distribution so I went along with what I know better.
- I set an axis to `tf.reduce_sum`. This was not giving any error because `log_prob` was executed before and failed, but it would have because when using multiple chains, each chain is independent, thus each chain has its log posterior probability. `posterior_log_prob` must return a tensor of length `n_chains`, not a scalar anymore.

Here is the resulting code omitting unmodified parts:

```py
observations = generate_bernouilli(N,p)[:, None, :]

# ---------- Model ------------#

def make_prior(D):
    one_theta = tfd.Independent(
        distribution=tfd.Uniform(low=tf.zeros(D)),
        reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1
    )
    return one_theta

def make_likelihood(theta):
    one_y = tfd.Independent(
        distribution = tfd.Bernoulli(probs=theta),
        reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1
    )
    y = tfd.Sample(
          one_y,
          sample_shape=(N,)
    )
    return y

def joint_log_prob(observations, D, theta):
    return (
        make_prior(D).log_prob(theta) + 
        tf.reduce_sum(
            make_likelihood(theta).distribution.log_prob(observations), 
            axis=0
        )
    )

posterior_log_prob = functools.partial(joint_log_prob, observations, D)

# Small comment, for coherence I would also modify the following line
current_state=tf.ones([n_chains,D])/10, 
# otherwise, D != 2 would not work
```